# Sidebar and navigation in Reactjs. routing inside rendered component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a simple User dashboard app. From top of the navigation, it link to user dashboard. In user dashboard, there is side menu, and user content. I have rendered Userprofile from App.js. Now, in the userprofile, when I click Account settings or others, they should replace Overview Component. But, when I click sidebar links, it goes to right path, example: /dashboard/profile/accountsetting, butthere is nothing on page.

Userprofile.js

```
   <div className="row mt-5">
      <Sidebar/>
       <Switch>
           <Route exact path="/dashboard/profile" component={Overview} />
           <Route exact path="/dashboard/profile/settings "component={AccountSetting} />
           <Route exact path="/dashboard/profile/passwordchange" component={PasswordSetting} />
      </Switch>
   </div>
```

Sidebar.js

```
<div className="profile-usermenu">
   <Link to="/dashboard/profile" >Overview</Link>
   <Link to="/dashboard/profile/settings">Accounting Settings</Link>
   <Link to="/dashboard/profile/passwordchange">Password Settings</Link>
   <Link to="/dashboard/info" className="border-bottom-0">Info</Link>
 </div>
```

Comment: Where is the <Router> Component?

Comment: It is in app.js component